# Discord.Js options object

Tags: discord.js

I'm actually doing a command to start a "conversation" with a player and take responses he give me. For doing that, I've the plan to use a temporary channel. I don't find a complet way to create a channel. I saw, that we have to create the channel, and after modifie it to adjust as we want. So I have this code :

```
m.guild.createChannel(`Candidature-${m.author.username}`, 'text', [{
    type: 'role',
    id: '605021521467146279',
    permission: 0x400
  }])
```

with this error :

```
(node:1904) DeprecationWarning: Guild#createChannel: Create channels with an options object instead of separate parameters
```

and I don't find real documentation about `options object`. Can I have some information about how it's work, and some link to learn more ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to use the [ChannelData Object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelData). Also, ``role`` is not a type, ``id`` is not an option and ``0x400`` is not a permission for text channels

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the confusion here as the way channels are now created have been altered and here is how to create them: (`var name = "blah"` isn't needed but cleans it up a bit)

```
var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" })
```

And to do the channel permissions you want to use `.then` like this:

```
message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
  (chan) => {
  chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find('name', '@everyone'), {
     'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
  })
```

You can change the role or change it to other things such as `message.author.id` or mentioned users etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that's what I did. I was missing some documentation to do it.

Discord channel data option : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelData
Discord permission usage :
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html

Comment: So this issue is all sorted now?

Comment: Yes ! I have to wait 3 hours to put my answer as accept.

Comment: Well, happy I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I have do this :

```
m.guild.createChannel(
      `Candidature-${m.author.username}`, {
        type: 'text',
        topic: `Salon de candidature créé par ${m.author.username} | Id du joueur : ${m.author.id}`,
        parent: idCategorie,
        permissionOverwrites: [{
            id: m.guild.id,
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          },
          {
            id: m.author.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          }
        ]
      })
    .then((chan) => {

      console.log("Channel create");

    });
```

With those links : 
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelData
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions

It's creating a channel with a name, a topic, and a categorie as parent. Only the plyaer itself and administrator can see the channel.